# Type 'System.Windows.UIElement' cannot be serialized when leaving the application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I've got this situation:

```
Custom Control -> Navigate to its Settings Page -> Tap on a button in the Settings Page -> Show a PhotoChooserTask
```

So, let's say that this custom control has to just show an image loaded from the user gallery.

When tapped on the user control, I show a XAML settings page in which there's a button to load the image from the gallery and this button launches the `PhotoChooserTask`.

Now, the problem is that it throws an exception right after launching the task.

Here's the stack trace:

```
    +       $exception  {System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type 'System.Windows.UIElement' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that the type is public and has a parameterless constructor - all public members of the type will then be serialized, and no attributes will be required.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.ThrowInvalidDataContractException(String message, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContract(RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type, SerializationMode mode)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ClassDataContractCriticalHelper..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContract(RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type, SerializationMode mode)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ClassDataContractCriticalHelper..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContract(RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type, SerializationMode mode)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ClassDataContractCriticalHelper..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContract(RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type, SerializationMode mode)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ClassDataContractCriticalHelper..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContract(RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type, SerializationMode mode)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ClassDataContractCriticalHelper..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContract(RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type, SerializationMode mode)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ClassDataContractCriticalHelper..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContract(RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type, SerializationMode mode)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ClassDataContractCriticalHelper..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContract(RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type, SerializationMode mode)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.GetDataContract(RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WriteKeyValueOfstringanyTypeToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at WriteArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyTypeToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(Stream stream, Object graph)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.BaseStreamPersister.Serialize(IDictionary`2 dictionary, IEnumerable`1 knownTypes)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.SaveState()
   at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.FireDeactivated(UInt32 reason)
   at Microsoft.Phone.TaskModel.Interop.ITask.Pause.Invoke(UInt32 reason)
   at Microsoft.Phone.TaskModel.Interop.Task.FireOnPause(UInt32 reason)}    System.Exception {System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException}
```

I understand that is totally related to application's state and I think that this happens because the OS is trying to "freeze" the app to resume its state after the task is completed.

What I do not understand is how this system works and what I must do to avoid the exception and make it correctly serialize my components.

Please keep in mind that I've got multiple levels of inheritance (something like `UserControl -> Custom 1 -> Custom 2 -> Custom 3 -> Current Custom Control).

Any idea?

EDIT:

After some experiments I found out that the exception is thrown everytime i leave the application, **but only if I am in the settings page.**

It doesn't matter if I leave it by starting the task or by hitting the windows button.

Now, this is the only page in which I used an external library (Coding4Fun Toolkit) so I guess that this is where the problem lays but I still don't get how to fix it or if this is bug of the library!

Comment: why do you EVER want to serialize a control?

Comment: Because the exception's message suggests me to do that..

Comment: Can you provide a repro at create a bug over at https://coding4fun.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create so I can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

This `InvalidDataContractException` is thrown when

> the DataContractSerializer or NetDataContractSerializer encounters an invalid data contract during serialization and deserialization. (from MSDN)

If you were trying to serialize something in your application around the area of your `UserControl`, then you have not implemented your serialization correctly... this can be fixed.

However, if you have no serialization or deserialization code in you application, then this serialization is being performed by a control or similar that you have added to your application... is *this* is true, then you have a bigger problem, as you probably don't have access to the code to fix the problem.

Referring to your comment 'Because the exception's message suggests me to do that', were you using serialization *before* you got this `Exception`?

Comment: I'm not using any kind of serialization in my code, and I'm only using the `Coding4Fun Toolkit` as external library